# Is $yy^\top $ always positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it true, that $yy^\top$ is always positive semidefinite? For any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, I find

$$x^\top (yy^\top)x=(x^\top y)(y^\top x)=(y^\top x)^\top(y^\top x)\ge 0$$

Does the same result apply to $x,y\in\mathbb{C}^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, notice that $y^t y = \sum_{i =1}^n y_i^2 \geq 0 $, also this works for complex inner product
Edit: the question changed, I think this works for $ \sum_{i=1}^n(y^t x)_i^2 \geq 0$ in the complex case one takes the conjugate $\sum \overline{(y^t x)}_i (y^t x)_i \geq 0$

Comment: I think it does not hold for $n=1$, $y=i$ and $x=1$? $x^\top (yy^\top)x=1\cdot i\cdot i\cdot 1=i^2=(-1)$

Comment: the inner product in the complex case has the complex conjugate $\overline{x}$

Comment: Great! That makes sense! Thank you so much for the fast reply!

Comment: You are welcome! If you agree with the answer and its helpful, you can accept with the green check :)